# SQLServer 2012 Error converting data type varchar to datetime

Tags: sql-server

We have a Stored Proc on SQLServer 2005. If I run it from SQL Management Studio in the form:

`exec spPerformance '13/09/2009 00:00:01','13/09/2017 23:59:59','D5A0700'',''D5A0900'',''Q1B1200'',''B2B0700'',''M1T0800'',''P1U0200'',''J2W0200'',''F5W0700'',''F5W0800'',''F5W1000','LN'',''MD'',''NE'',''NW'',''SC'',''SE'',''WS'`

it runs without issue.

I have another server with SQLServer 2012 and from the SQLServer2005 backup we did a restore to 2012. The collation on both are the same, but on 2005 the compatibility level is set to 90 and on 2012 set to 110. Additionally on the 2012 server there are additional properties of Default Language that set to `British English` and Default Fulltext Language LCID set to `1033`.

What do I need to do to get the SP to work on the 2012 server, we are likely to have 100's of SP's having datetime passed in, in this way.

Comment: Try passing the dates in "YYYY-MM-DD" format. That format is unambiguous, whereas 09/13/2009 could either be 13 September or an invalid date, depending on your server's regional settings.

Comment: @DeanOC if I change it to that I then receive the following error **The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value** the parameters on the SP are declared as 'datetime'.

Comment: If you get an out or range conversion error with the format @DeanOC gives you I suspect you have a data error, or are using an incorrect datatype (smalldatetime might not be what you want).

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen as mentioned to DeanOC in the SP it is declared as datetime not smalldatetime. I know the data is/should be fine as it works on its SQLServer 2005 counterpart. (Both DB's have the same data, and the same Stored Proc). so it's something to do with moving from SQLServer 2005 to SQLServer 2012

Comment: _What do I need to do to get the SP to work on the 2012 server_ What exactly does this mean? From SSMS? From your application? From some other tool? The short answer is use a format that is not dependent on language or other settings. The long answer is to read **and understand** how dates provided as strings are interpreted by the db engine - an exhaustive discussion is [here](http://www.karaszi.com/sqlserver/info_datetime.asp). And if there is an application involved, then parameterize the query rather than pass a string for execution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest explicit conversion.  Can you try following?  Pls let me know.

```
DECLARE @dd1 DATETIME
DECLARE @dd2 DATETIME
SET @dd1 = CONVERT(datetime, '13/09/2009 00:00:01' , 103);
SET @dd2 = CONVERT(datetime, '13/09/2009 23:59:59' , 103);
exec spPerformance @dd1
                 , @dd2
                 , ...
```

Anyway, I think you can try too the following (SET DATEFORMAT  which sets the order of the month, day, and year date parts -  See MS documentation)

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy; 
exec spPerformance '13/09/2009 00:00:01','13/09/2017 23:59:59', ...
```

Comment: in SQLServer Management studio if I do this, then it redlines under the sp name and the first Convert word. I tried adding `SET DATEFORMAT dmy` in the SP but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: can you add in your question script code of procedure? (at least the first part, declare parameters)

Comment: Strange I'd already tried placing `SET DATEFORMAT dmy;` above my Alter Procedure command, executing it then running the sp with no effect. I've just done the same cycle again and this time the SP has worked ????? Also strange is that as per my original question the language is set to British English so you'd have thought that the format would by default by uk formatting which is ddmmyyyy

Comment: @bilpor  I updated my answer (my fault: need to declare var for use in sp parameters a function)